# A differential equation with square root

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\dot{W}(t) = -\alpha W(t) + \beta e^{-\lambda t} \sqrt{W(t)}\\
&W(0) = W_0
\end{aligned}
$$

with $\alpha,\beta,\lambda$ positive constants.

What's $W(t)$ for $t\ge0$?

Comment: I was going for linear combinations of $e^{-\alpha t}$ and $e^{-\lambda t}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{\dot W}{\sqrt W}+\alpha\sqrt W=2\dot{\sqrt W}+\alpha\sqrt W=\beta e^{-\lambda t}.$$

Comment: Oh, great. So I can solve with Laplace for $\sqrt{W}$, and then just take the square, right?

Comment: @Antonio: yep (or even without Laplace).

Comment: And as long as the initial condition is positive, we only reach zero asymptotically, which makes dividing by $\sqrt{W}$ safe. I guess.